# Using embeddings to anonymize information

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, semantic-security

This might be a stupid question, so bear with me. I was wondering if LLM embeddings can be used to anonymize input text. I couldn't find any information online that says that embeddings can be 1:1 decoded back to the original text.

An example:
A user wants to check some metadata about a query with an external API, but doesn't want the exact text input to be sent to the API (it might contain personal/sensitive information).

Can he send the embeddings to the API, assuming the API can do meaningful checks on the embeddings - so the API will not have access to the original text?

Comment: LLM stands for Large Language Models; ChatGPT uses one. LLM embeddings are the data structures used by LLMs to encode the information initially fed during a training phase. LLM embeddings are the output of training, and an input of later phases. So the question proposes to train a LLM with input text, and send the data produced by the training to the API (it's _not_ proposing to make the API submit queries to the trained LLM, which could be another approach).

Comment: @fgrieu, Yes, so for example I would want to anonymise "yes, my name is John Doe (secret)" and so the API could understand that the message was a "yes" and that a name was provided but not the exact name "John Doe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question! However, it requires being a bit more formal about what "anonymization" means to answer properly. No approach will result in a leakage-free solution, since some information will always be revealed about the input unless you use encryption or [secret sharing](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/359168.359176) to hide the original input.

As you observed, embeddings are not one-to-one, which means some information will indeed be "lost" during the embedding phase. The problem is then to determine *how much* information is lost exactly, and making sure it is sufficient to hide sensitive information in your application/setting. Two possible approaches come to mind:

### (Local) Differential Privacy

To ensure that each embedding always loses "enough" information (here *enough* is a setting-specific parameter) to prevent the API from learning sensitive information about the query, we can inject some noise to the embedding and analyze the information loss through the [local differential privacy framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_differential_privacy). Interestingly, when embedding high-dimensional vectors into a low(er)-dimensional space via the [Johnson–Lindenstrauss transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma), it has been shown that the [embedding itself can be differentially private under the right parameters](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.2136.pdf).

### Probably Approximately Correct (PAC) Security

A [different approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.03458.pdf) (compared to local differential privacy) was recently proposed to capture the information leaked on an input $X$ from a mechanism $M$ applied on $X$. In your case, $M$ would be the embedding and $X$ would be the query. PAC security quantifies the leakage in a data-dependent way (whereas differential privacy considers worst-case data distributions). This appears to be closer to your goal of determining how "private" the embedding is. I recommend reading Section 7 and Appendix K of the [PAC security paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.03458.pdf) to get an overview and comparison to differential privacy.